# Display Top Level Categories and Current Categories SubCategories in magento

Tags: menu, magento-1.7, categories

When you hover over a category on the frontend, it displays the subcategories for this parent. When you click on the child category or the parent category, this subcategory listing disappears. 
What I want is to always display the subcategory if the parent category is selected, or any of the subcategories is selected. 
I have spent few days trying to figure this out and have given up. Tried going through the javascript as well, so that onClick it could display the subcategory as well. But that did not work.
I am using Magento 1.7.

Can someone please advice how I can achieve this top menu navigation?

Thanks,
Neet

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add "shown-sub" class to the active li child ul you want to show?
For example,

```
jQuery('#nav li.active>ul').addClass('shown-sub');
```